# ImportError: no module named pyslow.tool - how to 'use' pyslow 'correctly'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, python-module, yslow

Using `Pyslow` found at https://launchpad.net/pyslow, I've taken all the steps in the `README`. When I run the program, the message I get is

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pyslow", line 9, in <module>
import pyslow.tool
ImportError: No module named pyslow.tool
```

The file with which this is referencing is

```
import pyslow.tool

pyslow.tool.main()
```

I've hit the googles for this, but not getting to much feedback. Does anyone know how to 'overcome' this issue?

Comment: Do you have a file named `tool.py` in the `pyslow` package folder?

Comment: Yeah, its there - along with                               browser.py   engine.py    profiler.py   server.py  tool.py
database.py  __init__.py  reporting.py  test     To navigate to this folder - pyslow/pyslow/tool.py along with the other mentioned files.

Comment: Check PYTHONPATH, it might be a configuration problem then... Can't help you without more information :-)

Comment: Ok - ill check that - is there any more info that you would need that could* help? (by the way - huge thanks mate!)

Comment: Actually, it isn't a programming problem here I guess, it shouldn't be on S.O. But, you can try to import `pyslow` from a Python console and see if you can import `tool` as well. 
But I think it's just a path problem.

Comment: I get import error when i import tool or pyslow.

Comment: Solved the issue - what i did was place the pyslow directory into a pyScripts folder, so the working format is /home/me/pyScripts/pyslow Then do "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/me/pyScripts" and it worked.